# :AngularJS: ng-selected is not working with a true statement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-select

I have a a select box like this:

```
    <select class="form-control"
            ng-model="contactName"
            ng-change="testFun(contactName)"
            ng-options="contact.Id as contact.Name + ' ' + contact.Surname for contact in company.items.contacts"
            ng-selected="$scope.contactId === contact.Id">
    </select>
```

Where $scope.contactId = 14151 and contact.Id = 14151

But the select box is still not selecting the right person and remains to show up blank.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here.

**EDIT**

```
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="contactName"
        ng-change="testFun(contactName)"
        ng-options="contact.Id as contact.Name + ' ' + contact.Surname + ' id:' + contact.Id for contact in company.items.contacts"
        ng-selected="contactId == contact.Id">
 </select>
 <pre>
    contactId: {{contactId}}
 </pre>
```

Which results in the following, which also confirms that the ID's are the same:
[image: ContactId]
[image: Option with the same ID]

The box is still coming up blank

Comment: Can you confirm they're the same data type? === will not work for a string and a number even if they have the same value, whereas == will. Further to this - in your view `$scope` is implicit - you don't need to type this and doing so won't work unless your `$scope` has a `$scope` property.

Comment: Yeah try UncleDave's solution if it doesn't work try changing `ng-selected="$scope.contactId === contact.Id"` to `ng-selected="{{$scope.contactId == contact.Id}}"`

Comment: I have editted my post! but it still seems to come up as blank..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) this will work . You can not use `$scope` inside html . Removing the `$scope` would work .

```
<select class="form-control"
        ng-model="contactName"
        ng-change="testFun(contactName)"
        ng-options="contact.Id as contact.Name + ' ' + contact.Surname for contact in company.items.contacts"
        ng-init="contactName = contactId" >
</select>
```

[ngSelected](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected) does not work with [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) you must use `ng-init` instead.

Comment: i thought I did! but didn't had enough rep ;) now it works!

Answer (score 2):

From the AngularJS [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSelected):

> Note: ngSelected does not interact with the select and ngModel directives, it only sets the selected attribute on the element. If you are using ngModel on the select, you should not use ngSelected on the options, as ngModel will set the select value and selected options.

That being said, you should use `ng-init="contactName = contactId"` as @Noman suggested, which initializes the `contactName` variabile with the `contactId`, selecting the correct option subsequently.